# How to setup NHibernate criteria to perform such query?

Tags: nhibernate

How to setup NHibernate criteria to perform such query?

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS CNT, 
    l.CAMPAIGN_ID AS CAMPAIGN_ID,
    MAX(mc.NAME) AS CAMPAIGN_NAME
FROM
    SA_LEADS l
INNER JOIN
    SA_CAMPAIGNS mc
ON
    l.CAMPAIGN_ID = mc.ID
GROUP BY
    CAMPAIGN_SOURCED_ID
ORDER BY 
    CNT DESC
```

I have mappings for both tables `SA_LEADS` and `SA_CAMPAIGNS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me I would start with the element that I am trying to group by so I would start with a 
base of campaign. I can't tell from your query but I would assume that your mappings have a way of moving from campaign to sales lead. I have assumed this is called "SALES_LEAD_LIST"

I also like to make a small class to receive the projection result so would create something to hold the result.

```
public class CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE
{
    public CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE() {}

    public int CP_ID {get; set;}
    public string CP_NAME {get; set;}
    public int CP_NO_OF_SALES_LEADS {get; set;}
}
```

Once you have something to put your projection result in you can create a standard criteria and just push it into you new class through a projection

```
    ICriteria criteria = base.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(SA_CAMPAIGNS));

    criteria.CreateAlias("SALES_LEADS_LIST", "SA_LEADS", JoinType.InnerJoin);

    criteria.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()                                         

            .Add(Projections.Property("ID"), "CP_ID")                
            .Add(Projections.Property("CAMPAIGN_NAME"), "CP_NAME")    
            .Add(Projections.CountDistinct("SA_LEADS.ID"), "CP_NO_OF_SALES_LEADS")    
            .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("ID"));
            .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("CAMPAIGN_NAME")));

    IList<CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE> cpProjections = criteria
                    .SetResultTransformer(
                       new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE)))
                    .List<CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE>();
```